# Tree view is not updating in background

Tags: c#, treeview, backgroundworker, directoryinfo

here it is the FULL source code : http://pastebin.com/mLaGwwi0
As you will notice , the thing is to scan directories and files and populate them in a tree view. I am using background worker (the same happens with Threads class) to do that in background, while updating treeview with nodes one by one.
The thing is that it is not working in background and not updating the treeview. This is the part of code which is hanging the form :

```
public void ListDirectory(DirectoryInfo path)
{
    treeView1.Nodes.Add(CreateDirectoryNode(path));
}

public void Addnode(DirectoryInfo dirinfo)
{
    Invoke(new AddCDAnode(ListDirectory), new object[] { dirinfo });
}

private TreeNode CreateDirectoryNode(DirectoryInfo directoryInfo)
{
    var directoryNode = new TreeNode(directoryInfo.Name);
    foreach (var directory in directoryInfo.GetDirectories())
    {
        //Statustext = directory.FullName;
        directoryNode.Nodes.Add(CreateDirectoryNode(directory));
    }
    foreach (var file in directoryInfo.GetFiles())
    directoryNode.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(file.Name));
    return directoryNode;
}

public delegate void AddCDAnode(DirectoryInfo dirinfo);

private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"\\server\trabajos 2013\");
    Addnode(dir);
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Start filling the TreeView on a separate thread
    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

In full source code you will see commented code - that is from example and working in background without any troubles. So i think the problem is with my code of scanning directories.

The solution is [also available here](https://www.wetransfer.com/downloads/3081d2a00af8150c352723d3a88a5c9c20130911190759/623fb154a192e25fa4fa9a3a1f617a1220130911190759/f5e4c8), if you want to download it.

Comment: That doesn't look like source code...

Comment: It is pretty long, that's why i posted it to Paste Bin , you can see link at the end of my message. Please remove "minus" from question and  read whole post. Thanks.

Comment: https://www.wetransfer.com/downloads/3081d2a00af8150c352723d3a88a5c9c20130911190759/623fb154a192e25fa4fa9a3a1f617a1220130911190759/f5e4c8 - this is the link encoded in goo.gl :)

Comment: @Oleg.Budeanu You shouldn't just be providing a huge dump of code and saying "fix it".  If you have so much code that you can't fit it into the question then it's a sign you have too much; you should work to determine what is and isn't relevant so that you can include enough code to demonstrate the problem, but while not including code that isn't relevant to the problem.  Do some tests to see what is and isn't working properly to narrow down the scope of what might not be working.

Comment: ok, edited - first is the link to pastebin, as the code is pretty long. If someone wants to download solution - it is in goo.gl shortened link...

Comment: @Servy I did not ask "fix it", and i am lost in finding the solution. As i mentioned before - i have 2 actions there. One is working in background. Second is for some strange reason working but NOT in background - hanging the main thread. First is just 2 for loops filling the TreeView , the second is a recursive scan through folders. And the question is - why first is not hanging the thread , but the second is ?

Comment: @Oleg.Budeanu Apologies, I see that goog.le link is a downloading service, that wasn't entirely obvious when I first visited the link as it was asking me to confirm terms and policies and such.  But I would second Servy's comments.

Comment: @CodingGorilla Ok , i've edited the post and added the "trouble" code part.

Comment: @Oleg.Budeanu Fantastic.  It's a short but complete code snippet that demonstrates the problem but contains no code not needed to demonstrate that problem.  It's a fantastic example.  Had you included something like that to begin with the question would likely have been received quite a bit more positively.

Comment: @Servy Oh well i did not know that and i'm kind of new to StackOverflow and to C# programming also... Though i am really desperate with my problem..

Comment: @Oleg.Budeanu That's why I helped you through it.  You've just had a good learning experience which you can use to help you when asking questions in the future, in addition to improving this question to the point where it's answerable.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you start a background thread, but then immediately go and call `Invoke` to run basically all of your real code in the UI thread, consequently the UI thread is being blocked.

What you need to do is separate out your UI logic from your non-UI logic.  Ensure that the non-UI logic is executed in the background thread, and that the UI logic is executed in the UI thread.

In this case, `CreateDirectoryNode(path)` is basically all of your non-UI work.  It's doing a whole bunch of file manipulation (which is time consuming) and in general creating the data that your UI will later use.

That should be done in the `DoWork` event of your background worker.  Then you can set the `Result` property of the BGW based on the results it generated so that it can be used later.

For the UI portion, which is the `treeView1.Nodes.Add(` call, that should be in the `RunWorkerCompleted` event.  That event is designed for you to manipulate the UI based on the results of the long running task.  There you can read in the `Result` property of the BGW (it is a property in the arguments passed to the event handler) and there it can add the data to the tree view.  Since this is in the UI thread you won't get cross thread exceptions, and since your long running file IO is done in the background thread it won't hand the UI.

So all you need is your `CreateDirectryNode` method and the following:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"\\server\trabajos 2013\");
    e.Result = CreateDirectoryNode(dir);
}

//TODO ensure that this event handler is added to your BGW so it actually fires
void Form1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    treeView1.Nodes.Add((TreeNode)e.Result);
}
```

Comment: That's great explanation, but the point is to add items to TreeView one by one as they are being scanned. That's why i am using invoke method to access the TreeView and to add nodes one by one. But i understand what you described there and will try to implement that with my needs. Thanks for help.

Comment: @Oleg.Budeanu That's important information to include in your question; that completely changes the way you should approach a problem like this.

Comment: i said it there.. " I am using background worker (the same happens with Threads class) to do that in background, while updating treeview with nodes one by one." Sorry that it wasn't obvious..

Comment: The only thing which comes to my mind is to place "addnode" method to progresschange of BW.

Comment: @Oleg.Budeanu That's one way of organizing it, although it's a bit more complex than that.  You still need to ensure that your long running tasks are run in the background thread, and then you can have it update progress with a new node that should be added, and then have the node actually be added in the progress changed handler.

Comment: @Oleg.Budeanu Another option is to change the requirements, which I would suggest if possible.  Instead, don't build the whole tree at the start.  Add the root node, all children, and their children, but go no deeper than that.  Then subscribe to the event of a node being expanded and, at that point in time, add all of its grandchildren so that its children can be expanded.

Comment: The problem is that the structure is pretty simple - it is about 2 folders with 1000+ files in it. I will try to implement the first thing , maybe my knowledge will be enough for that. Thanks for help.

Comment: can you please give me a hint about "it's a bit more complex than that" ? I am still stuck with this problem and cannot find a way to resolve it...

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24237/A-Multi-Threaded-WPF-TreeView-Explorer - this is just perfect example of what i need to do , but it is written in WPF.

Comment: @Oleg.Budeanu That link does more or less what I described earlier.  Rather than loading everything, but in the background, instead just load the nodes that need to be visible and then add their child nodes whenever a node is expanded given that there is an event that is fired when a node is expanded.  You said you didn't want to do that.

Comment: I just said that my structure of folders is simple - it has 1 root folder and 2-3 subfolders where we already have the 1000+ files. What i wanted to show here is that nodes are being added as they load , not at once , but one by one. In my case it will be by 20 nodes for example. I cannot find a way to do that.

Comment: @Oleg.Budeanu So then the link isn't doing what you want to do, despite you saying that it's a perfect example of what you want to do.

Comment: Ok, stop. Here it is the task. I want to load in background 20 by 20 files from subfolders when they are expanded (i agree with your way to do that , it is a good idea). After that as 20 files has been loaded - pass and add them to treeview in UI thread. In this example it is done , the difference is that it is one by one and it is in WPF , and some methods are being used, which are unknown for me and i do not know their analogs in WinForms...